# Package organisation in Python

Tags: python

I am having problems to manage my modules and pacakges dependencies in Python. I am in Windows 7 and using Python 3.3
I want to have a basic structrure like this:

```
/
myTask.py
-->utils
   --> utils1.py
   --> utils2.py
-->processes
   --> process1.py
   --> process2.py
```

MyTask will run process1. Process1 imports process2 and imports the utils1 and utils2 in the utils package

So in process1 I have

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..path..\\utils\\')
from utils1 import *
from utils2 import *
from process2 import *

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    my_method()

def my_method():
    ####CODE
```

I can run Process1 as script and works fine.
MyTask.py looks like:

```
import processes.process1
process1.my_method()
```

When I run it I recieve and error that says:

```
 ImportError: No module named 'process2'
```

Is my package/module structure correct? Why do I receive that error?

Comment: Have you tried adding directory containing myTask.py to your PYTHONPATH?

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in the structure you have created.

First of all, in python package must contain `__init__.py` file at it's root. It's ordinary python file and it might be completely empty. It's required to mark folder as python package

Next, you shouldn't mess with `sys.path` excplicitly, especially using relative paths (unless you are sure what you are doing, but this time you definitely not).

So, the correct folder structure would be

```
/MyTask.py
/processes
    __init__.py
    process1.py
    process2.py
/utils
    __init__.py
    utils1.py
    utils2.py
```

And `process1.py`:

```
from utils import utils1, utils2  # relative import
import process2                     # import from same package

# everything else
```

`MyTask.py`:

```
import processes.process1
process1.my_method()
```

More on packaging in [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Comment: I have the `__init__.py` I didn't include them for simplification. I tried "from utils import utils1, utils2" in the past but didn't work. I received the error message: "ImportError: No module named 'utils'"

Comment: It should be `__init__.py`, not `init.py`. Note underscores. And you shouldn't omit them as they are quite relevant.